# WPF User Control children not updating c#

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I am trying to add a child control (`UserControl`) to a `Grid` and the changes are not reflecting. But if another child control (`UserControl`) is added to the same grid then layout gets updated and both child are visible. This operation perform on button click.

```
/*this Operation is perform in Backgroud Worker */
void func()
{
    /*adding first User Control*/
    addRemoveChild(true,FirstChild);//even tried to run this fuc with Dispatcher    
    FixButton();
    addRemoveChild(false,FirstChild);
}

void addRemoveChild(bool isAdd,UserControl uc)
{
    if (isAdd)
    {
        parentGrid.Children.Add(uc);         /*parentGrid is Parent Grid*/
        parentGrid.UpdateLayout();

        return;
    }
    else
    {            
        parentGrid.Children.Remove(uc);
        parentGrid.UpdateLayout();
    }
}

void FixButton()
{
    /* here some operation is perform which takes 5 min to complete till then FirstChild is not visible*/

    addRemoveChild(true,secondChild);                              /*When this Func run the first Child is visible*/
}
```

Comment: make sure your UI Thread is not getting blocked because of 5 min operation inside FixButton() method

Comment: and try to comment that 5min operation and check what happens?

Comment: You better update your whole code including 5 min operation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is performed in a background worker: It's not done in the Dispatcher Thread. Every time you use a Dispatcher object (an object that has been created by the Dispatcher thread such as Controls) you should be in the Dispatcher thread.

The background worker is useful to perform task and update UI relative to the task's status in "real time".

You aren't using the background worker correctly. The code in the DoWork is executed in a separate thread whereas the ProgressChanged callback is executed in the Dispatcher thread.

What your code should look like this:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (sender, args) => {
    bw.ReportProgress(0);
    FixButton();
    bw.ReportProgress(100);
};

bw.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.ProgressPercentage == 0) {
        parentGrid.Children.Add(uc);
    } else if(args.ProgressPercentage == 100) {
        parentGrid.Children.Remove(uc);
    }
};

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

By the way you don't need to call UpdateLayout() and your DoWork callback function should never use Dispatcher objects (remove addRemoveChild from FixButton function)

Comment: Same thing really, but as an alternative look into using Task.Run as well. Quite a bit you can do with Async and Await around it.