# C# wpf adding children to Layout asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.7.2

I have a WPF application where I am running a powershell script that returns a sequence of strings. I want to be able to update my UI asynchronously, but the UI will only update once the method is complete. How do I update the UI asynchronously? I have been reading a lot of other similar examples like this one: [WPF User Control children not updating c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149436/wpf-user-control-children-not-updating-c-sharp) Maybe this works, but I could be implementing it incorrectly?

My code:

```
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunPreCheck();
        }

public void RunPreCheck()
        {

            var startInfo = GetPowerShellStartInfo();
            proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {

                string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                var myObject= new MyCustomObject(line);
                myGrid.Children.Add(myObject);
          
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `RunPreCheck()` on a background thread:

```
private void NextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(RunPreCheck);
}

public void RunPreCheck()
{
    var startInfo = GetPowerShellStartInfo();
    proc = Process.Start(startInfo);

    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

        myGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(() => myGrid.Children.Add(new MyCustomObject(line))));

    }
}
```